# Dynamic SQL Pivot by Column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Supossing we have `n` columns with `m` rows

```
table 1:

someName1  someName2  someName3 ... someNameN
----------------------------------------------
12.5       12.34      56.6     ...    33.2
1.2323     12.5       57.2     ...    123.1
2.789      45.2       766.1    ...    56.2  
45.23      34.3       7.4      ...    33.4
52.1       4.3        89.8     ...    67.3
```

How to use dynamic SQL to do in general

Output (`A table with n rows`, with,autoincrement ID, column name of Table1 and Sum of column like):

```
ID    Column     Result
--------------------------------
1     someName1  SUM(someName1)=12.5+1.2323+2.789+45.23+52.1
2     someName2  SUM(someName2)=12.34+12.5+45.2+34.3+4.3
3     someName3  SUM(someName3)=56.6+57.2+766.1+7.4+89.8
...   ...
...   ...
N     someNameN  SUM(someName3)=33.2+123.1+56.2+33.4+67.3
```

Where `SUM(columnName)` is the value of summing all values of `Table 1,` How to do this for any size of any table, where `n` could be `50`, in other words a `table with 50 columns`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might look like this:

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(128) = N'table_with_50_columns'
declare @columnLikeFilter  nvarchar(128) = N'someName%'

declare @columns nvarchar(2000) = '';
declare @sumColumns nvarchar(2000) = '';

select @columns = @columns + COLUMN_NAME + ',',
       @sumColumns = @sumColumns +  'sum(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') as ' + COLUMN_NAME + ','
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = @tableName and COLUMN_NAME like @columnLikeFilter
order by ORDINAL_POSITION ;

set @columns = left(@columns, len(@columns) - 1) ;
set @sumColumns = left(@sumColumns, len(@sumColumns) - 1) ;

declare @sql nvarchar(4000) =
    N';with cteColumnts (ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME) as 
    (
        select ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where TABLE_NAME = N'''+ @tableName + ''' and COLUMN_NAME like ''' + @columnLikeFilter + '''
    ),
    cteValues (ColumnName, SumValue) as
    (
        SELECT ColumnName, SumValue
        FROM 
           (SELECT ' + @sumColumns + '
           FROM dbo.' + @tableName + ') p
        UNPIVOT
           (SumValue FOR ColumnName IN 
              (' + @columns + ')
        )AS unpvt 
    )
    select row_number() over(order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as ID, ColumnName, SumValue
    from cteColumnts c inner join cteValues v on COLUMN_NAME = ColumnName
    order by ORDINAL_POSITION'

--print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql
```