# exec sp_executesql @sql and exec (@sql)  SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

A Dynamic SQL query from [lobodava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239890/dynamic-sql-pivot-by-column-sql-server) is:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) =
    N';with cteColumnts (ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME) as 
    (
        select ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where TABLE_NAME = N'''+ @tableName + ''' and COLUMN_NAME like ''' + @columnLikeFilter + '''
    ),
    cteValues (ColumnName, SumValue) as
    (
        SELECT ColumnName, SumValue
        FROM 
           (SELECT ' + @sumColumns + '
           FROM dbo.' + @tableName + ') p
        UNPIVOT
           (SumValue FOR ColumnName IN 
              (' + @columns + ')
        )AS unpvt 
    )
    select row_number() over(order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as ID, ColumnName, SumValue
    from cteColumnts c inner join cteValues v on COLUMN_NAME = ColumnName
    order by ORDINAL_POSITION'
```

**exec sp_executesql @sql

--OR

exec (@sql)**

Why did lobodava pick `exec sp_executesql @sql` and not `exec(@sql)`
So what is the difference here?
Is it better to use `sp_executesql on recursive dynamic queries`?
In other post they say `sp_executesql` is more likely to promote query plan reuse...
So it helps in these kind of queries?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `EXEC sp_executesql` will cache the query plan -- `EXEC` will not.  For more info, and a very good read, see:

- [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Caching a query means that the logistics to the query are temporarily stored, and make running the query later on faster for it.

Comment: So, it is good to use,`sp_executesql` on this kind of query because  of query `plan`, right?

Comment: @darkcminor: Yes, `EXEC sp_executesql` should be what you use in the majority of cases, when you have to use dynamic SQL on SQL Server.